# Infor LN (Baan) - Hello World Programming

Tags: erp, baan, infor-ln

I'm starting my journey into Infor LN (which I understand to be derived from BAAN.

Is there a simple 3G Script available, like a 'hello world'?

If so, is it possible to read directly from the command line?

I understand there are no tags but I'm hoping this question can help bootstrap it as very little is available online.

Comment: Yes I know, downvotes for lack of research but my research has yielded nothing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infor LN is a 4GL development environment. There is a model for the database, and you operate on that data by means of a standard framework that you extend with your coding.

Super-basic Infor LN concepts you should be aware of:

- A "Session" is the main entity a user interacts with
- It contains the definition of the fields of the form
- It links to a "UI Script" aka "Session Script"
- When running a session, a program contained in the framework retreives data from the database according to the session definition and the data model (called the "runtime data dictionary") and does all the basic CRUD stuff. This is called the "standard program". It calls your UI script based on events (user tabs out of a field, pushes a button etc.)
- A "DAL" is a script that's called from the standard script whenever it does something with a database record (inserts it into a table, changes a field's value). So this is also sort of event based programming, but based on on data events, not on user events
- Typically you will be using that type of event based programming.
- There is an option to run scripts without a UI. They are called 3GL-Programs. A simple "Hello world" would be

function main()
{
   message ("Hello World")
}

Basic resources: https://docs.infor.com/ln/ce/en-us/lnolh/default.html
Documentation->Enterprise Server->Tools

Most active web community: baanboard.com

However, if you are a total newbie you will need some sort of introduction (training) to this development environment. It is a totally proprietary environment with 30 years of history, very little public ecosystem, and not much documentation. In my opinion, it is close to impossible to figure out for yourself how the building blocks fit together. Additionally, it is also rather easy to bring your production system down with beginner's mistakes. You should be aware of these.

hope that helps a litte

Uli

Comment: Thank you! I think you are the first step towards there being more online. Is it possible to run "hello world" from a shell, such as bshcmd?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't run an Infor LN program from a shell, and if you do, it would be headless, so no output possible. It's possible though, and there are situations where it's actually used. But if you want to learn the software, you need to start from within LN, you need to start with the concept of a session.